# На что влияет модификатор static в классе? C#

Tags: c#, классы, static

Статический класс не может обращаться к своим нестатическим полям, поэтому разумеется, если у нас в классе должны быть нестатические поля, то класс static не помечаем

Но как быть в обратном случае?

У нас есть два класса, у них имеются только статические методы, один помечен static, другой нет

```
public class A
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}

public static class B
{
    public static void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A.Foo();
        B.Bar();
    }
}
```

Работают они абсолютно одинаково

И вот тогда возникает вопрос, зачем помечать класс как статичный?
Меняется ли от этого хоть что-то?

Comment: Вы не можете для статичного класса создать экземпляр, сделать `var foo = new Foo();`, а соответственно сделать несколько экземпляров. Учите ООП. Знание ООП снимет вопрос об экземплярах, статике и прочих фокусах. Пометка класса как `static` запрещает вызов его конструктора, избавляет вас от лишних ошибок при написании кода.

Comment: а теперь попробуйте `var a = new A();` и `var b = new B();`

Comment: А главное в официальной документации ведь всё написано https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members